# TemplateSyntaxError at / 'pages_extras' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of in Django 2

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

I am sorry, I have a question:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /
>   'pages_extras' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
>   admin_list
>   admin_modify
>   admin_static
>   admin_urls
>   cache
>   i18n
>   l10n
>   log
>   static
>   staticfiles
>   tz

Comment: can you post the entire Traceback you got in the question too?

Comment: this error is due to some template tag not loading up

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your post is missing some question and probably some more details. Please edit your question that it's clear what you're asking and include the required information to answer. Our guide [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might be helpful for you. Thanks!